# PayPal Orders v2: the approveurl of the order ("checkoutnow?token..") returns 302 redirect

Tags: dart, paypal

I am struggling creating an order with Orders v2 PayPal API.

I have the token, and I do a request with these headers to create the order:

```
{
  "intent": "CAPTURE",
  "purchase_units": [{
    "description": "Payment",
    "amount": {
      "value": 'X',
      "currency_code": "EUR",
      "breakdown": {
        "item_total": {
          "currency_code": "EUR",
          "value": 'X'
        },
      }
    },
    "items": [{
      "unit_amount": {
        "currency_code": "EUR",
        "value": 'X'
      },
      "quantity": "1",
      "name": 'item name',
    }]
  }],
  "application_context": {
    "brand_name": "My brand name",
    "locale": "it-IT",
    "return_url": 'my-return-url',
  }
}
```

The order is created and I get the `approveurl` to let the user to pay.

With the `approveurl` I do this call:

```
try {
  var response = await http.post(approveurl, body: jsonEncode({"payer_id": payerId}), headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json",
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
  });

  final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return body;
  }
  return null;
} catch (e) {
  rethrow;
}
```

But I get this reponse:

```
url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=..."
payerId = "..."
accessToken = "..."
response = {Response}
 request = {Request} POST https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/checkoutnow?token=...
 statusCode = 302
 reasonPhrase = "Found"
 contentLength = 61
 headers = {_InternalLinkedHashMap} size = 9
     0 = {map entry} "paypal-debug-id" -> "95934918777a1"
     1 = {map entry} "cache-control" -> "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     2 = {map entry} "location" -> "/webapps/hermes?token=..."
     3 = {map entry} "set-cookie" -> "X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DSANDBOX3.WEB.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dhermesnodeweb%26TIME%3D1595167415%26..."
     4 = {map entry} "date" -> "Sun, 19 Jul 2020 14:03:35 GMT"
     5 = {map entry} "vary" -> "Accept"
     6 = {map entry} "strict-transport-security" -> "max-age=63072000"
     7 = {map entry} "content-length" -> "61"
     8 = {map entry} "content-type" -> "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
 isRedirect = false
 persistentConnection = true
```

And the `response.body` is:

```
Found. Redirecting to /webapps/hermes?token=...
```

Comment: Sounds fine to me. Maybe you should follow the redirect.

Answer (score 2):

> With the approvalurl I do this call:

The approval URL is not for you to call. It's a web URL, not an API URL. It's for the paying customer to log in and give their approval of the payment.

However, redirecting them to it would be a bad web experience. For modern web design, you should instead offer an "in context" approval, where your site remains loaded in the background.  Here's how to do that: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

With this integration you don't read the approval_url yourself, simply return the Order id when fetched from createOrder.